# Hashing multiple Strings into one Hash

Tags: java, algorithm, hash, hashmap

I hava a array of many strings. And I want to create one hash. First I hashed all strings of that array like here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strings.length(); i++)
{
    strings[i] = hash(strings[i]);
}
```

So now I have hashes at level 1. Like on picture below. Is there any algorithm for do the next steps? I do not want to making merkle tree.

[image]

Comment: According to what logic e.g. hash 01 and hash 02 are matched?

Comment: This has nothing to do with hashes, this is a question about for loops. After the first hashing you have demonstrated, feed the array into another for loop that process two elements at a time and output a shorter array. Then repeat until you have one element left in the output. The whole process including your for loop can be written as a recursive function.

Comment: do you actually need hashes for every level?

Comment: You got to decide whether the position of the elements matters, i.e., whether `{"a", "b",}` shall have the same hashCode as `{"b", "a",}`. Next, check if one of the methods provided fits the bill (without regard of being in a position to use them). If rolling your own, either choose symmetrical functions to combine values, or asymmetrical ones.

Comment: why not hash the string which is concatenation of all substring?

Answer (score 4):

I feel `Arrays.hashCode(Object a[])` can be used.

Please have a look if `Arrays.hashCode(Object a[])` helps.

```
String[] strings = {"Hello 1", "Hello 1", "Hello 1"};
int hasCode = Arrays.hashCode(strings);
System.out.println(hasCode);
```

Answer (score 3):

If I were you, I would join all strings into one, and then hash that long string.

Eg.

```
        StringJoiner j=new StringJoiner("");//Or any other separator
        Arrays.asList(strings).forEach(j::add);
        String finalHash=hash(j.toString());
```